# Why does Stream.max accept Integer.compare as an input parameter?

Tags: java, java-stream, comparator, method-reference

The stream.max method takes a Comparator but Integer.compare does not implement Comparator interface. The only similarity is they share same method signature of compare() method. So I am quite confuse about what are the prerequisites to become a Comparator input parameter? Thank you.

Example:

```
List<Integer> ls = Arrays.asList(9,2,5,8); 
System.out.println(ls.stream().max(Integer::compare).get());
```

Answer (score 2):

Because in this context, `Integer::compare` is equivalent to its lambda form:

```
(a, b) -> Integer.compare(a, b)
```

And this lambda form is also logically equivalent to its anonymous class form:

```
new Comparator<Integer>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(Integer a, Integer b) {
        return Integer.compare(a, b);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The [`Comparator` interface](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) is a functional interface, so any lambda expression or method reference whose method signature conforms to the functional interface may be used.

The `compare` method takes two objects, compares them, and returns an `int` for ordering purposes.  The method reference `Integer::compare` refers to [`Integer`'s `compare` method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#compare(int,int)), and that method's signature matches, so the compiler allows this method reference to resolve to a `Comparator` instance.

Lambda expressions and method references are allowed when passing as an argument to a method, assigning to a variable, and as an argument to a cast operator.  Here, your method reference is being passed to a method as an argument, so the compiler sees this as legal code.

Answer (score 1):

`Integer.compare(int, int)` has a signature that we can use to implement `Comparator<Integer>.compare(Integer, Integer)`. Because `Comparator` is a functional interface, we can use a method reference to `Integer.compare` to supply an implementation of `Comparator<Integer>`.

This form uses the `static` method `Integer.compare(int, int)`.
In this case, when the stream is comparing two elements, it makes the following static call:

```
Integer.compare(element1, element2);
```

`Integer::compare` can be used to provide an implementation of any functional interface that has the same signature, such as:

```
BinaryOperator<Integer> bo = Integer::compare; //int functName(int, int)
BiFunction<Integer, Integer, Integer> bf = Integer::compare;

//or even
BiConsumer<Integer, Integer> bc = Integer::compare; //return value ignored
```

A different form of your method reference is to use:

```
System.out.println(ls.stream().max(Integer::compareTo).get());
```

In this case, to compare two elements, the stream calls:

```
element1.compareTo(element2);
```

The second form uses the instance variant `integer.compareTo(otherInteger)` (the actual instances used as target and parameter are resolved at runtime when the stream is comparing elements two by two in this case).
This is based on:

[JLS-15.13.3 Run-Time Evaluation of Method References](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.13.3):

> If the form is ReferenceType :: [TypeArguments] Identifier, the body of the invocation method similarly has the effect of a method invocation expression for a compile-time declaration which is the compile-time declaration of the method reference expression...
>
> ...
>
> - If the compile-time declaration is an instance method, then the target reference is the first formal parameter of the invocation method. Otherwise, there is no target reference.
> - If the compile-time declaration is an instance method, then the arguments to the method invocation expression (if any) are the second and subsequent formal parameters of the invocation method. Otherwise, the arguments to the method invocation expression are the formal parameters of the invocation method.

Describing the details of how the method references are resolved, validated, and called would be too much to be included here, so it's definitely a good idea to go through this section of the JLS :-)